# Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be established

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

Your application could not be compiled, because its dependencies could not be established.
  The following Dart file:
  C:\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\foundation.dart
  ...refers, in an import, to the following library:
  C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\meta-1.1.5\lib\meta.dart
Unfortunately, that library does not appear to exist on your file system.

Comment: when i run that on flutter console i get the error...



C:\Users\dblacklagosboy>flutter packages get
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

it says that you are trying to import a library that does not exist.try to run 
`flutter packages get` that will get the packages you need and this might solve your problem

Comment: C:\Users\dblacklagosboy>flutter packages get
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks... I solve by running the
        flutter packages get 
Although I tried this before as a i was connected to slow internet, but the moment i was on a faster internet it worked... thanks

Sorry for the bad formatting, i'm new here.

Comment: Instead of Posting it as an New Answer you should have selected the already given same answer that did solve the issue with a comment that it needed faster internet in your case.